# How to instruct Dockerfile RUN to run different commands in different shells?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

A script I want to run in my Dockerfile requires a database up and running first. So tried to do something like this.

```
FROM postgres
COPY toBeExecutedAgainstRunningDB.sh .
RUN  postgres start && sh toBeExecutedAgainstRunningDb.sh
```

This doesn't work since `postgres start` gets executed first and the result is a running database but the shell prompt just hangs there and the second command in my RUN `sh toBeExecutedAgainstRunningDB.sh` never gets executed. I want to be able to run the script while the database is still running. Is there a way to do that with `RUN`?

Comment: There is, but you probably don't want to do this. If you look at the [documentation for the postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), you will see there is a way to run scripts against the database at *runtime* rather than at *build* time. See the "Initialization scripts" section.

Comment: You probably don't want to run your application and the database in the same container, and the Dockerfile can't connect to other containers.  If the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism that @larsks mentions doesn't work for you, your other major option is to do the database setup in an entrypoint script before it launches the application.

Comment: As you both guessed it my intent is to initialize the database and create few schemas and tables. My first attempt was to use `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mechanism like @larsks suggested, but this only worked for .sql files. My .sh script requires the DB to be running and listening on localhost:5432 which is the default port. The script fails with `connection refused to localhost:5432`. My script uses [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) to create more schemas and tables.

Comment: Yes, the script is basically its own project and should be running on its own container but I was hoping to create a customized Postgres image with schemas and tables already initialized.

Comment: Any changes you make to the database in the Dockerfile won't be visible in a running container. You can only meaningfully interact with the database at runtime, not at build time.